# Regex "Append" or "Replace" only the first letter of each word?

Tags: c#, regex

If I have two words such as "ga ?abg"

I want to remove the first two characters in the second word if they match "?a" and take the after "b" and append it to the first word?

How can I do that? please help

```
string five ="ga ?abg";
string T = Regex.Replace(five, "?a", " ");
```

But how to append the first "b" ?

The result should be "gab g".

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to get as a result?

Comment: The first tow character?

Comment: `two words such as "ga ?abg"` Are they *words*? What do you mean by "word"?

Comment: @JamesDidzun. Don't you have characters in your tow?!

Comment: No, I don't have any characters in my tow- Whatever that is.

Comment: assume they are words it just for dictionary project and the above is just an example sorry if does't make sense.

Comment: @JamesDidzun. _a **tow** is an untwisted bundle of continuous filaments, and it refers to man-made fibres, particularly carbon fibres_ Now you know it...

Comment: @gdron   
Verb: 
(of a motor vehicle or boat) Pull (another vehicle or boat) along with a rope, chain, or tow bar.
Noun: 
An act of towing a vehicle or boat.
The coarse and broken part of flax or hemp prepared for spinning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want something like this, though I don't use c#, so the syntax might be wrong.  (Also, your description is confusing, so I may not have understood what you want)

```
Regex.Replace(five, "([^ ]+) \\?a([^ ])", "$1$2")
```

Where:

- "(...)" is a matching group, and $n copies the contents of the nth matching group
- "[^ ]" means "any character except a space
- "[^ ]+" means "one or more non-space characters"
- "\?" means "a literal question mark", since question marks are special in regexps

Comment: I want to appent the first character of the second word to the first word if it start with certain pattren. other example "per aldwa" if the word start with the pattren "al" it will omit the "al" and apend the "d" to the "per"->"perd wa"

Comment: @Iman25 Looking at the C# docs, it looks like you probably want to use `"$1$2"` rather than `"\\1\\2"` (this is the kind of thing that differs from one implementation of regexp to the next, and as I said, I haven't used the c# version).

Answer (score 0):

I think the Regular Expression you are looking for is this:

```
/ \?a./
```

Since I don't know any C#, Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8MsqW/1/) (I kept it simple incase you do not know any js)

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason this has to be Regex?

```
string answer;
string[] split = five.Split(' ');
if (split.Length == 2 && split[0].Length > 0 && split[1].StartsWith("?a") && split[1].Length > 3)
{
    answer = string.Format("{0}{1} {2}", split[0], split[1].Substring(2, 1), split[1].Substring(3));
}
else
{
    answer = five;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a [MatchEvaluator Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but that still requires custom code.  I don't think you can do what you're asking through a simple `Regex.Replace`.